# Internet explorer - how do you escape single quotes

Tags: .net, internet-explorer

In internet explorer how do I escape single quotes.

`&apos;` works for firefox etc but internet explorer doesn't like it.

For instance

```
<input type="text" value='Single quotes `&apos;` Here' />
```

works in firefox but not in IE

Comment: Can you show an example of where you are using it?

Comment: Can you clarify your question more? Escape in a URL? Escape in JavaScript?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

&apos; is not valid HTML - it is an XML only sequence. FireFox is simply sharing a little too much code between its html and xml parser. Use the &#39; sequence (the correct html escape for ') as already suggested.

Answer (score 5):

Use `&#39;`

You can view a list of all the [ISO-8859-1 HTML entities (escape codes) here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp).

Answer (score 3):

As AJM said in a comment, I'd try this:

`<input type="text" value='Single quotes &#39; Here' />`

Answer (score 3):

You could surround that particular attribute value with double quotes, and put the single quote in directly.

It appears, also, that some versions of Internet Explorer (correctly) don't recognize the `&apos;` entity in HTML, only in XML, so you may have some luck with `&#39;`.